# Node js and mysql date

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using node js and mysql database
I use code like this to print my table ibb.co/np1uwx It is html and the result is from the sql query
When I select date from mysql and display it, the result is like this:
Mon Mar 13 1978 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

How can I only display "Mon Mar 13 1978"

Comment: I recommend [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) library dealing with dates.

Comment: I use code like this to print my table
https://ibb.co/np1uwx
It is html and the result is from the sql query,still the same?